# Working on DOM elements, finding next class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with working on DOM elements.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="movie__feature">
    <a href="#" data-value="86" data-user="35" class="voting plus">▲</a>
</div>
<div class="movie__images">
    <span class="similarity_points">9</span>
    <a href="http://www.filmypodobnedo.pl/Top-Gun/" title="Filmy podobne do Top Gun">
        <img alt="Filmy podobne do Top Gun" src="http://www.filmypodobnedo.pl/photos/Top-Gun.jpg"/>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="movie__feature">
    <a href="#" data-value="86" data-user="35" class="voting minus">▼</a>
</div>
</div>
```

When I click on .plus class, I need to go to .similarity.

This is my jQuery:

```
$('.plus').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    self.closest('div').find('.similarity_points').text('10');
}
```

How my num should look?

Comment: `console.log` and see ??

Comment: @Mritunjay where I should look on consol.log? How I can figure it out by consol.log?

Comment: @gehleh Yep, I want to changevalue of .similarity_points but I cant reach it out by DOM elements, something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest div doesn't contain `.similarity_points` as a descendent. You could use this:

```
self.closest('div').parent().find('.similarity_points').text('10');
```

But, be aware that code which is highly dependant on the structure of the DOM is also fragile.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are going up to `.movie__feature`, and then you are looking for children with the `.similarity_points` class.

You need to go up one more level and *then* look for the child element:

```
$('.plus').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').parent().find('.similarity_points').text('10');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The siblings option doesn't quite work, since `.similarity_points` is a child of a sibling div, not a sibling itself.

Comment: @Paulpro Hm, it did not occur to me. I removed that part from my answer. Thank you.